# Quartus ii - How to manually set coordinates of blocks or elements

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am trying to implement TDC on Altera FPGA so i need to make carry chain with carefully placed delay elements. I was searching and found a lot of examples for XLINX where manually placing of elements is done with attributes which are given to wanted element. One of the examples is below:

ATTRIBUTE LOC OF delayblock : LABEL IS "X_SLICE"&INTEGER'image(Xoff)&"Y"&INTEGER'image(Yoff+i);

Quartus ii compiler can't recognize such statment. On other hand i didn't found any examples for Quartus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just typing "quartus fpga manual placement" into Google, I found [this Application Note](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/an/an578.pdf). While it talks about placing PLLs specifically, it seems to show the general technique for placing any resource.

Apparently it involves a lot of tedious mucking around in a GUI, rather than a direct edit of a text file. Maybe you can figure out which file the GUI is actually modifying and work directly with it instead.